# Magento 2 Website taking too much time to load?

Tags: magento2, optimization, time, pagespeed

I have created a website using Magento 2.1.12, after that, I have added some categories and products from the Magento backend.

Is it taking too much time to load the front site as well as the admin portal?

Is anyone having the solution to reduce the loading time?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Have you enabled cache.? If not the Go to admin > system > Cache Management and select all cache type and enable it.

Comment: Is your website running in production mode? run "bin/magento deploy:mode:set production" in your shell

Comment: Use Memcached on your server also use varnish on Magento(recommended). redis cache and PHP-fpm is useful too. after all just set gzip and minify CCS and JS and merge them. you can decrease load time from 23S to 3.6S